# Substrate node template: ./scripts/docker_run.sh command does not work

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I am trying to execute the above command but have the following issue:

```
[+] Running 7/7
 ⠿ dev Pulled                                                                                                     98.3s
   ⠿ d121f8d1c412 Pull complete                                                                                    6.0s
   ⠿ 1b985895e9b7 Pull complete                                                                                    6.1s
   ⠿ 809a473c961b Pull complete                                                                                    6.2s
   ⠿ 89f7c794c3df Pull complete                                                                                    6.6s
   ⠿ ea120af1c111 Pull complete                                                                                   68.8s
   ⠿ de2c35bb8bf1 Pull complete                                                                                   96.1s
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠋ Container node-template  Creating                                                                               0.1s
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /host_mnt/Users/ep/IdeaProjects/demo/substrate-node-template/.local
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `.local` is missing. Try:

```
touch .local
```

Comment: I don't know how that script is supposed to be used, but maybe worth opening an issue and amending it.